# why all objects properties are printed when we assign only one to a variable and print it

Tags: javascript

I am new Javascript while practicing I came across a point as

I have object with some properties and their values,though I have assigned only one property to var x as below, why and how come it prints all  property values instead of only one as "New York City" in output

```
 var city= {
    fullName: "New York City",
    mayor: "Bill de Blasio",
    population: 8000000,
    boroughs: 5
};

    // write a for-in loop to print the value of city's properties
    var x= "fullName";
    for(var x in city){
    console.log(city[x]);
    }
```

Actual output is :
New York City
Bill de Blasio
8000000
5

rather than "New York City" only

Comment: `for (var x in city) {` for will go through all keys in the city object. If you want to get the fullName, just use `city['fullName']`

Comment: Why are you using for-in loop? Totally redundant

Comment: Your `"fullName"` is actually not used and will be overwritten by `for`.

Comment: Because the loop will reset the value of x. If you print the x inside the loop you will understand the value of x is getting reset.

Comment: the x declared before for loop is in different scope than the one you are again declaring in forloop. In forloop you are intializing and looping each property of city object.

Comment: i didn't get that, when I assign x="fullName", how come it refers to other property value in for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Javascript structure:

```
for(var x in city){...}
```

is for iterating ALL enumerable properties and does not care what the initial value of `x` is before the loop.  Instead, this structure just declares that `x` will receive the next property name for each iteration of the loop and the initial value of `x` has no influence on the `for` loop at all.

If you want the output to only contain `"New York City"`, then you would just do this:

```
var x= "fullName";
console.log(city[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

x in your for loop doesn't refer to the value "fullName". It takes each key of the object you are iterating through i.e through each key in the object "city" in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Because the loop will reset the value of x. If you print the x inside the loop you will understand the value of x is getting reset.

If you just want the value from the city object with key as **fullName** and in your case **x**, then you can directly use. city[x];

```
 var city= {
    fullName: "New York City",
    mayor: "Bill de Blasio",
    population: 8000000,
    boroughs: 5
 };

 var x= "fullName";
 console.log(city[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

the for loop used by you will reset the value of x every time, irrespective of the initial value you assign in this case "x", so by this, it prints all property value the object refers to in your case it is "city"